# Runtime error in sorting a singly linked list

Tags: c++, sorting, infinite-loop, singly-linked-list

I have written a linked list(which is aimed for the data type int) implementation.
Seems to be working fine **except** when I try to sort the list in such a way that all the odd
elements should come after all the even elements with the original order of the even and odd numbers preserved.

Upon debugging in MS Visual Studio, I found out that in the `oddevenSort()` function, the for loop seems to be going on infinitely...as if somehow the `tail->next` was not being updated to `nullptr`.
I can't seem to grasp where the error lies in my logic.

```
#include<iostream>

template<class T>
class SLL_Node
{
public:
    T info;
    SLL_Node* next;
    SLL_Node();
    SLL_Node(T el, SLL_Node<T>* n = nullptr);

};

template<class T>
class SLL
{
private:
    SLL_Node<T>* head, * tail;
    size_t size;
public:
    SLL();
    ~SLL();
    bool isEmpty() const;
    size_t get_size() const;
    void add_to_head(T el);
    void add_to_tail(T el);
    void delete_at(size_t); //delete at a certain index. Index starting from 1. Throws an error //message if index out of bounds or list empty. 

    void display()const; //the logic is for mostly primitive data types and not user defined data //types (including classes)
    void oddevenSort();
};

template<class T>
bool SLL<T>::isEmpty() const
{
    if (tail == nullptr)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

template<class T>
SLL_Node<T>::SLL_Node() : next{ nullptr }
{}

template<class T>
SLL_Node<T>::SLL_Node(T el, SLL_Node<T>* n) : info{ el }, next{ n }
{}

template<class T>
SLL<T>::SLL()
{
    size = 0;
    head = tail = nullptr;
}

template<class T>
void SLL<T>::add_to_tail(T el)
{
    ++size;
    if (!isEmpty())
    {
        tail->next = new SLL_Node<T>(el);
        tail = tail->next;
    }
    else
        head = tail = new SLL_Node<T>(el);
}

template<class T>
void SLL<T>::add_to_head(T el)
{
    head = new SLL_Node<T>(el, head);
    if (tail == nullptr) //if empty
    {
        tail = head;
    }
    ++size;
}

template<class T>
void SLL<T>::display()const
{
    std::cout << '\n';
    for (SLL_Node<T>* tmp{ head }; tmp != nullptr; tmp = tmp->next)
    {
        std::cout << tmp->info << "->";
    }
    std::cout << "NULL\n";
}

template<class T>
void SLL<T>::delete_at(size_t index)
{


    if (index >= 1 && index <= size) //bound checking 
    {
        if (!isEmpty()) //we dont need is empty since size takes care of that but still adding it for clarity
        {

            if (head == tail && index == 1) //if list only has one node and we delete head node
            {
                delete head;
                head = tail = nullptr;
            }

            //otherwise if list more than one node

            else if (index == 1) //if deleting head node
            {
                SLL_Node<T>* tmp{ head };
                head = head->next;
                delete tmp;
                tmp = nullptr;
            }

            else //deleting other nodes
            {
                SLL_Node<T>* tmp{ head->next }, * pred{ head };
                for (size_t i{ 2 }; i < index; ++i)
                {
                    tmp = tmp->next;
                    pred = pred->next;
                }
                pred->next = tmp->next;
                if (tmp == tail)
                {
                    tail = pred;
                }
                delete tmp;
                tmp = nullptr;
            }

        }
    }

    else
    {
        std::cout<<"\nError! Either the list is empty or the index entered is out of bounds!\n";
    }
}

template<class T>
void SLL<T>::oddevenSort()
{
    SLL_Node<T>* t=head;
    size_t count{1};
    for (; t != nullptr; t = t->next)
    {
        if (((t->info) % 2) != 0)
        {
        add_to_tail(t->info);
        delete_at(count);

        }
        ++count;
    }
}
```

**main**:

```
int main()
{
    SLL<int> a;
    a.add_to_head(1);
    a.add_to_head(2);
    a.add_to_tail(3);
    a.add_to_tail(4);
    a.add_to_head(6);
    a.add_to_tail(7);
    a.add_to_head(5);
    a.display();
    //a.oddevenSort();
    a.display();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `delete_at(count);` doesn't that cause an issue with what `t` points to?

Comment: @drescherjm I have added the `delete_at()` definition now. Please have a look

Comment: The problem is not delete_at() it's what `t` points to. You delete the node that t points to then after that try to do `t = t->next` on the deleted node

Comment: So should I do `t=t->next` before calling `delete_at(count)` ?

Comment: You probably should not use delete_at() in this function. And remove `t = t->next` from the for (;;) instead put `t = t->next` in the body of the loop and only use it when you don't delete.

Answer (score 0):

Consider an example input for `oddevenSort` `a(1)->b(2) ->c(3)->null`

1. on 1st iteration `t` is pointing to `a(1)` new node is created with
   data `1` which is appended at the end of list like
   `b(2)->c(3)->d(1)->null`.
2. On 2nd iteration `t` will point to node `b(2)` and no changes done
   on list.
3. On 3rd iteration `t` will point to node `c(3)` new node is created
   with data `3` which is appended at the end of list like
   `b(2)->d(1)->e(3)->null`.
4. on 4th iteration `t` will point to `d(1)` which creates new node at the end of list. Iteration goes on and on recursively without breaking the loop.

Every time you need not to delete and create the new node. You can segregate even and odd nodes and make final list.

Here is the updated snippet

```
template<class T>
void SLL<T>::oddevenSort()
{
    SLL_Node <T>tempOddHeader;
    SLL_Node <T> *tempOddPtr = &tempOddHeader;
    SLL_Node <T> tempEvenHeader;
    SLL_Node <T> *tempEvenPtr = &tempEvenHeader;

    SLL_Node<T>* t = head;
    tempOddHeader.next = nullptr;
    tempEvenHeader.next = nullptr;

    while(t)
    {
        if (((t->info) % 2) != 0) {
            //append to the odd list
            tempOddPtr->next = t;
            tempOddPtr = tempOddPtr->next;
            t = t->next;
            tempOddPtr->next = nullptr;
        }
        else {
            //append to the even list
            tempEvenPtr->next = t;
            tempEvenPtr = tempEvenPtr->next;
            t = t->next;
            tempEvenPtr->next = nullptr;
        }
    }

    tempEvenPtr->next = tempOddHeader.next;
    head = tempEvenHeader.next;
    tail = tempOddPtr;
}
```